# my express api works in postman but not when calling from react.It gives "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am creating url shortner using react and nodejs. user inputs url in react and then press submit to triggerpost request. It works fine with postman but doesn't when calling from react. I tried calling post request on different url, it works but it doesn't with work with express url
This is react front end part which calls post after submitting url

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = {
      originalUrl: this.state.originalUrl
    }

    const item = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/post", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(url)
    })
    console.log("item",item)
  }
```

This is express part which works fine with postman

```
router.post('/post', async (req,res) => {
    const originalUrl = req.body.originalUrl;

    const urlCode = random()

    var newInput = new model({
        originalUrl,
        urlCode
    })

    var item = await newInput.save()

    return res.json({
        originalUrl:originalUrl,
        urlCode:urlCode,

    })
```

Comment: Post Method requires 2 argument so pass like these **await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",null,{})** Use axios instead of fetch and put them into try catch i think this will work for you

Comment: This may be due to CORS. See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719041/how-to-resolve-typeerror-networkerror-when-attempting-to-fetch-resource/51161180). Is your API server running on the same domain that the app is being served from? If it isn't, try running them on the same domain. You may need to [enable CORS in the Express server](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) and add a cors header to your request.

Comment: sorry. i meant to write http://localhost:5000/api/post in fetch url instead of that link.i tried withtry and catch still shows same error. front end and express are running in two different port

Answer (score 1):

It might be an error of cors. You need to use the cors npm package in your server code. Use the cors as middleware. You can include this line in your index file at server-side code:-

```
app.use(cors())
```

Visit the site given below for using cors.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) mechanism gives web servers
>   cross-domain access controls, which enable secure cross-domain data
>   transfers. Modern browsers use CORS in an API container - such as
>   XMLHttpRequest or Fetch - to mitigate risks of cross-origin HTTP
>   requests. (Source:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

There are different ways to handle this, and one simple way is you need to install chrome extension [Moesif Orign & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc)
and the other way you check your installed extension by disabling one by one from chrome://extensions/ and then check one by one which extension is making this issue.