# HTML, Javascript: When doing fetch from ONCLICK error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript

This is baffeling.

I am getting this error in firefox console:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

When calling this function:

```
function sendMSG() {


  let functionName = "getAllUsers"

    let url = "https://api.kumulos.com/b2.2/asd/"+functionName+".json";
    let username = 'asd';
    let password = 'dsa';
    
    let headers = new Headers();
    
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + username + ":" + password);
    
    fetch(url, 
      {method:'POST',
       headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username+ ":" + password),
                },
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));


}
```

from HTML:

```
<button onclick="sendMSG()">Click me</button>
```

When I call this message from the code itself, it works flawlessly, but as soon as I try the click I am just getting the above error.

On Chrome I am getting no errors, but also no results.

Is this my fault?

Comment: may be check [cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719041/how-to-resolve-typeerror-networkerror-when-attempting-to-fetch-resource)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to post the event from HTML:

event = event || window.event;
event.preventDefault();