# Scapping webpage using Js gives Network Error

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a simple website it works for same domain but when i try to scrape for another domain it give network error `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

```
async function scrapeWebPage(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const html = await response.text();
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

    // Extract the titles of all the links on the page
    const titles = [];
    const links = doc.querySelectorAll('a');
    links.forEach(link => {
      titles.push(link.getAttribute('title'));
    });

    console.log(titles);
    alert(titles);
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error scraping webpage:', error);
    alert(error);
  }
}

scrapeWebPage('https://www.w3schools.com/');
```

Can we get around network error using pure javascript

Comment: This will not be allowed under `CORS` policy of browsers. Please search for that, and you will get an explanation as to why browsers won't allow this kind of behaviour. A quick search for your error (which you really should have done), this is the _first_ SO answer that comes up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719041/how-to-resolve-typeerror-networkerror-when-attempting-to-fetch-resource - And it seems rather relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719041/how-to-resolve-typeerror-networkerror-when-attempting-to-fetch-resource)

Comment: @somethinghere, Is there any other alternative as i wanted to do it using pure JS, When i disable CORS on Chrome it works, Not sure if there is solution to this problem.

Comment: There is no solution if this is browser side only, otherwise CORS would be meaningless,  but your back end, eg PHP / nodeJS etc can act as a proxy.

Comment: As @Keith says, there is no solution, as it’s done for security purposes. Security doesn’t work if you can just turn it off for yoir users.

Comment: Yes i agree as it works only when i disable CORS on browser so only way around i server level script. PHP, Python or .net