# Error when I try to fetch file from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm able to successfully upload a json file to the Firebase Cloud Storage service.

But when I try to download the same  file, "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." appears.

My js code is:

```
const storage = firebase.storage();
// Obtén una referencia al archivo que deseas descargar
const fileRef = storage.ref().child('json_data/data.json'); // Ajusta la ruta del archivo

// Descarga el archivo y procesa los datos
fileRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    console.log("DOWLOADING");
    console.log(url);

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // Aquí 'data' es el objeto JSON descargado
      console.log("LO TENEMOS");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error al descargar y procesar el archivo:', error);
      console.log(error)  <--- ERROR HERE
      console.log(url);
    });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error al obtener la URL de descarga:', error);
});
```

Any idea about that? Maybe is CORS  problem? I am unable to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You "upload json file to firebase/firestore"  (a No SQL DB ) and use a method from Cloud Storage Client SDK, i.e.  `getDownloadURL()` (An object storage service)

Comment: so, what method I need use?

Comment: You should give more details on what you are exactly doing for uploading (within Firestore?), i.e. share the code and also what is your goal.

Comment: I just update my code.

Comment: Nowhere in your code you upload a file to Cloud Storage. Can you share a picture of your Cloud Storage console to see if there is a file?

Comment: problem is not on uploading(is another js file).

Comment: Do you get a correct URL when doing `console.log(url);` If you open it via a browser do you get the JSON file?

Comment: yes, I get the corect json file on browser

Answer (score 0):

The problem most probably comes from the fact you are not correctly [chaining the Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) returned by the different asynchronous methods.

The following should do the trick:

```
fileRef.getDownloadURL()
  .then((url) => {
    console.log("DOWLOADING");
    console.log(url);
    return fetch(url);
  })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((data) => {
    // Aquí 'data' es el objeto JSON descargado
    console.log("LO TENEMOS");
    // Check here that data is correct
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error al descargar y procesar el archivo:', error);
    console.log(error) < --- ERROR HERE
    console.log(url);
  });
```

Comment: tnanks. that code get the same error and the response code part not reached

Comment: From where do you execute this code? I guess it is the code of a web app?

Comment: It is a web app on my local execution

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719041/how-to-resolve-typeerror-networkerror-when-attempting-to-fetch-resource

Comment: Also, did you try after deploying the app to e.g. Firebase Hosting?

Comment: I need to deploy to firebase hostingo ot dowload a file? from other app (mobile io version, I get files )

Comment: No you don't need, but you may eliminate the potential CORS problem if you deploy it to Firebase Hosting or any other internet provider